# Let $X$ be a finite set such that for all $x \in X$, $x$ is finite. Then, $\bigcup X$ is finite.

Tags: set-theory

Let $X$ be a finite set such that for all $x \in X$, $x$ is finite. Then, $\bigcup X$ is finite.

We define the natural numbers $\omega$ as $0 = \emptyset, 1 = \{0\}, 2 = \{0,1 \}, n = \{0,1,...,n-1\}$.

I'm with difficult to formalize this argument. My attempt:

By hypothesis, exists a bijection between $X$ and some natural number $n \in \omega$. Then, $X = \{ x_0,...,x_{n-1} \}$. Besides this, for each $i \in n$, exists some $m_i \in \omega$ such that $x_i = \{ x_i^{0},..., x_i^{m_i-1} \}$.
Since $y \in \bigcup X \iff \exists x \in X, \, y \in x$,
$$ y \in \bigcup X \iff \exists i \in n, \exists j \in m_i, \, y = x_i^{j}. $$

Hence, $\bigcup X = \{ x_i^{j}: \, i \in n,  j \in m_i  \}$.

How can I define a bijection from $\bigcup X$ and some $m \in \omega$?

Thank you!

Comment: What is $\bigcup X$ where $X$ is a (finite) set? What does it mean for a set $X$ to be in bijection with a natural number?

Comment: @AdLibitum I've edited the question, a set $X$ to be in bijection with $n$, we consider $X$ to be in bijection with $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$.

Comment: still there are some hypotheses which are left unexplained. Are you assuming that the elements of $X$ are themselves (finite) sets? Are you trying to say $\bigcup_{x\in X}x$ when you write$\bigcup X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume the elements of $X$ are disjoint. Let $m = \max \{m_0,...,m_{n-1}\}$. Then for each $i\in n$, there exists an injective $f_i: x_i\to m$. It would suffice to find an injection $g: \bigcup X \to nm$. In fact, given $x\in x_i \in X$, let $g(x) = im+f_i(x)$. Can you show that $g$ is injective?

Comment: The X being disjoint being "without loss of generality" should have more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a finite set means it has $N$ elements $x_1,...,x_N$ for some integer $N$. Each $x_k\in X$ is finite means each $x_k$ has $n_k$ elements, where $n_k$ is some integer for each $k$. Let $M=\max_{k\in\{1,...,N\}}n_k$. Then $\cup X$ has at most $NM$ elements.